# div showing up twice in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html

I'm almost finished a site , but for some reason it's not appearing as wanted in IE. The div "content" (with top border) is showing up twice - once with the content in it, centered, and again below the navigation, but aligned to the left and with no content in it. It is showing up fine in Safari and Firefox.

Here is the CSS code:
    #content {

```
#content {
    position:relative;
    top: 50px;
    width:900px;
    height:580px;
    border-top-color:#000000;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-width:1px;
}
```

And here is a link to the site: http://www.thomas-collection.eu/home.html

Thank you!

Comment: why are you using the `center` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validating your HTML will fix the problem (you have an open DIV among other things.)

http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thomas-collection.eu%2Fhome.html

Comment: Thanks so much! That validating website is a great tool and helped me clean up my coding. I'll definitely have that bookmarked.